# Why to develop 64 bit APK for Android L ? Apart from performance improvement what else we will achieve?

Tags: android, 64-bit, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to understand why to create 64 bit APK for Android L 64 bit devices.
Apart from the major performance improvement what else we will gain ?

Or what functionality we will not be able to use if we use 32 bit APK in 64 bit devices ?